# jquery append functionality disordered the html layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

I'm working on a small project : (calculator), phase 1 --> get the template ready
using jquery & bootstrap

The problem appeared when I put a big number inside the target container using `jquery.append`, the layout become disordered, any idea how to fix that .. ??

this is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <div class="row well" id="result" style="margin-top: 15px; min-height: 85px;"> <!-- this is the container -->
        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> ² </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Exp() </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Log() </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
      <?php for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++)
      {?>

        <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block num" data-num="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?> </button>
        </div>

      <?php } 
      ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"> C </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block"> = </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block opper" data-op="+"> + </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block opper" data-op="-"> - </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block opper" data-op="/"> / </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block opper" data-op="x"> x </button>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {

    $( ".num" ).click(function() {
      var num = $(this).data('num');
      $('#result span').append(num);

    });

    $( ".opper" ).click(function() {
      var op = $(this).data('op');
      $('#result span').append(op);

    });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'disordered'? Aside from needing to limit the length or scroll the display, it seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/232v8c9d/

Comment: if you put a big number . the numbers get out of the container

Comment: @AbdessamadEzaimi Will it be fine if the text continues to the next line?

Answer (score 1):

> if you put a big number . the numbers get out of the container

In this case you need to set the `span` containing the numbers to scroll when a large number is entered, which you can do with the following CSS:

```
#result span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/232v8c9d/7/)

Alternatively you can amend the JS to limit the number of characters which can be entered:

```
$(".num").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).data('num');
    var $span = $('#result span')
    if ($span.text().length <= 10)
        $span.append(num)
});

$(".opper").click(function() {
    var op = $(this).data('op');
    var $span = $('#result span')
    if ($span.text().length <= 10)
        $span.append(op)
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/232v8c9d/5/)

Personally, I'd use the latter.

Also note that you can join the two function handlers in to one:

```
$(".num, .opper").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data($(this).hasClass('num') ? 'num' : 'op');
    var $span = $('#result span')
    if ($span.text().length <= 10)
        $span.append(value)
});
```

Comment: @AbdessamadEzaimi Remember to accept this as to correct answer once you can.